# How to check for uniqueness in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes where each hash contains a handful of keys. I want to check to see if any number of the hashes have the same user_id.

An example would look like this:

```
[ {:id => 1, :user_id => 2, :location => nil, :facility_id => nil}
  {:id => 3, :user_id => 2, :location => 'China', :facility_id => 20} ]
```

I would need this to return true in this case, where two of the hashes have a user_id in common. How do I do this the 'ruby way'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a.map{|t| t[:user_id]}.uniq.size == a.size
```

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [ {:id => 1, :user_id => 2, :location => nil, :facility_id => nil},
  {:id => 3, :user_id => 2, :location => 'China', :facility_id => 20} ]
p arr != arr.uniq{|u| u[:user_id]} #=> true
```

Comment: My idea was almost the same but one note - comparing the sizes should be enough. Comparing the whole arrays will be slower.

Comment: @izomorphius Ruby seems to [optimize for this](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/hash.c?v=1.9.1-p431#1449) (line 1463). But generally speaking, you are right.

Comment: this optimization works only for the false case. Imagine you have an array with 10 hashes with different user_id-s and each hash has a size of hundreds of megabytes.